# Create pdf file

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

What is the best way to generate pdf file over JavaFX gui app?
I used iText library,and works well.Does exist other way to create pdf,or just this library can use to generate pdf files.

Comment: What is the exact reason for you to look for another library?

Comment: I don't know,maybe an easier way to generated them...

Comment: I'm afraid as is the question is too broad - if you have specific problems with iText or specific requirements please edit your question to specify them, otherwise it's really hard to recommend any specific solution.